# inDesign scripting update data source of data merge

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

All i want is a script, which update added file in data merge.

Why this don´t work?

```
app.activeDocument.dataMergeProperties.updateDataSource();
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
I have to open panel DATA MERGE before i call update function.

```
app.panels.item("data merge").visible = true;
app.activeDocument.dataMergeProperties.updateDataSource();
```